# Bar graphs that don't start at 0 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to show the available range of travel of a machine that has 360 degrees of rotation and that has another axis of motion with a range of -5 to 152 that is independent of yaw. All of the bar graph drawing functions I can find assume that data start at 0 and this leaves a hole in the middle of the graph between -5 and 0. Is it possible to tell geom_bar() or geom_col() to start drawing at -5 instead of 0?

Here is the code that I'm using and an example graph.

```
df <- data.frame(0:360)
colnames(df) = "Yaw"
df$Max.Static <- ((runif(361) * 157)-5)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x =Yaw , y = Max.Static)) + 
  geom_col(width = 1, alpha = .5 , fill = "#69B600") + 
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(-5,152),
    breaks = seq(0,140,20)
    ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    limits = c(-1,361),
    breaks = seq(0,360,45),
    minor_breaks = seq(0,360,15)
    ) +
  coord_polar(theta = "x") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Transform your data adding 5 so it does start at 0, but adjust the labels, and then do the inverse transform on the labels so that the start is labeled -5. (Though in this example there are no radius labels, so no one will be the wiser...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of a weird hack, but the following works if you can tolerate a warning:

```r
df <- data.frame(0:360)
colnames(df) = "Yaw"
df$Max.Static <- ((runif(361) * 157)-5)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x =Yaw , y = Max.Static)) + 
  geom_col(width = 1, alpha = .5 , fill = "#69B600",
           aes(ymin = after_scale(-Inf))) + ######## <- Change this line
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(-5,152),
    breaks = seq(0,140,20)
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    limits = c(-1,361),
    breaks = seq(0,360,45),
    minor_breaks = seq(0,360,15)
  ) +
  coord_polar(theta = "x") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: ymin
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

It works because we can access the rectangle parameters (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) after the bar parametrisation has been converted to rectangles with `after_scale()`.

The `-Inf` instructs ggplot that the variable should be at the minimum of the scale (even after expansion), hence closing the gap.

Comment: Is it possible to get it to properly graph a negative value to go from say -5 to -2 or is that asking too much?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but you can change the `-Inf` to whatever you like.

Comment: this is actually a weird hack, ..;)especially because you can just use geom_rect directly...

Comment: Using `geom_rect()` or `geom_tile()` is much more appropriate, as I'm abusing an aesthetic that is not made available to the user. However, you'd have to reparametrize to declare xmin/xmax or width/height if you use the standard rectangles and tiles. The nice thing geom_col/geom_bar does is do this reparameterization for you.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you should be looking at geom_segment or geom_rect, rather than geom_bar, as conceptually bar graphs represent count, therefore always starting at 0

Here with geom_segment. No hack needed.

```r
df <- data.frame(0:360)
colnames(df) = "Yaw"
df$Max.Static <- ((runif(361) * 157)-5)
df$y <- -5

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(Yaw , y, xend = Yaw, yend = Max.Static)) + 
  geom_segment( color = "#69B600", size = .2) + 
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(-5,152),
    breaks = seq(0,140,20)
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    limits = c(-1,361),
    breaks = seq(0,360,45),
    minor_breaks = seq(0,360,15)
  ) +
  coord_polar(theta = "x") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]

or, with geom_rect, to get the windmill style

```
    ggplot(df, aes(xmin = Yaw-0.4 , ymin = y, xmax = Yaw +0.4, ymax = Max.Static)) + 
      geom_rect( fill = "#69B600") + 
      scale_y_continuous(
        limits = c(-5,152),
        breaks = seq(0,140,20)
      ) +
      scale_x_continuous(
        limits = c(-1,361),
        breaks = seq(0,360,45),
        minor_breaks = seq(0,360,15)
      ) +
      coord_polar(theta = "x") +
      labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) + 
      theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
            axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Good point, just the continuous region created by the bar plot is why I went for a polar chart. With random data it isn't obvious, but I try to use segment with real data the width either has to be so large to bridge the gaps that it covers some useful data, or there are gaps in the plot where the data is constant.

Comment: @BrettKSmith not sure I understand. there is geom_rect as well, which should make your windmill style effect, see added graph. I really don't see the need for geom_bar